Simple CRUD server in rust
This is my first rust application.  I tried to pick somewhat low level dependencies to get a feel for the language particulars.
I'm especially interested in control flow/error patterns in rust as I had some initial struggle.
update_comment is also a mess. I tried for a good hour to generically convert a JSON value into the dynsql type but was unable to get anything to work. Largely making the types compliant didn't work, but also casting Number ran into memory lifetime issues. Even with my hard coded approach, I had to throw the values on the stack (is it the stack? Up to rust?) in order to not have lifetime issues.
use clap::{self, Parser};
use regex::Regex;
use rusqlite;
use serde;
use serde_json;
use std::error::Error;
use std::io::Cursor;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use subtle::ConstantTimeEq;
use tiny_http::{Header, Request, Response, Server, StatusCode};

#[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
struct Comment {
    id: i64,
    message: String,
    author: String,
    created_at: String,
    approved: bool,
}

#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct NewComment {
    message: String,
    author: String,
}

#[derive(serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize)]
struct UpdateComment {
    approved: Option<bool>,
    message: Option<String>,
    author: Option<String>,
}

type RouteResponse = Response<Cursor<Vec<u8>>>;

// Keep in sync with row_to_comment
const ROW_QUERY: &str = "id, message, author, approved, created_at";
fn row_to_comment(row: &rusqlite::Row) -> Result<Comment, rusqlite::Error> {
    return Ok(Comment {
        id: row.get(0)?,
        message: row.get(1)?,
        author: row.get(2)?,
        approved: row.get(3)?,
        created_at: row.get(4)?,
    });
}

fn default_response(code: u16) -> RouteResponse {
    let code = StatusCode(code);
    let data = code.default_reason_phrase().as_bytes().to_vec();
    let len = data.len();
    return Response::new(
        code,
        vec!["Content-Type: text/plain".parse::<Header>().unwrap()],
        Cursor::new(data),
        Some(len),
        None,
    );
}

fn respond_with_json<T>(code: u16, data: &T) -> Result<RouteResponse, Box<dyn Error>>
where
    T: ?Sized + serde::Serialize,
{
    let data = serde_json::to_string(&data)?.into_bytes();
    let len = data.len();
    return Ok(Response::new(
        StatusCode(code),
        vec!["Content-Type: application/json".parse::<Header>().unwrap()],
        Cursor::new(data),
        Some(len),
        None,
    ));
}

fn read_json<T>(request: &mut Request) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>
where
    T: serde::de::DeserializeOwned,
{
    if !request
        .headers()
        .iter()
        .any(|h| h.field.equiv("Content-Type") && h.value == "application/json")
    {
        return Err("Content-type must be application/json".into());
    }
    let parsed: T = serde_json::from_reader(request.as_reader())?;
    return Ok(parsed);
}

fn list_comments(
    request: &mut Request,
    conn: &rusqlite::Connection,
    admin_password: &str,
) -> Result<RouteResponse, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut statement = conn.prepare(&format!("SELECT {} FROM comments", ROW_QUERY))?;
    if check_authorization(request, admin_password) {
        statement = conn.prepare(&format!(
            "SELECT {} FROM comments WHERE approved = 1",
            ROW_QUERY
        ))?;
    }
    let comments: Result<Vec<Comment>, _> = statement.query_map([], row_to_comment)?.collect();
    return respond_with_json(200, &comments?);
}

fn create_comment(
    request: &mut Request,
    conn: &rusqlite::Connection,
) -> Result<RouteResponse, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let comment: NewComment = match read_json(request) {
        Ok(comment) => comment,
        Err(e) => return respond_with_json(400, &e.to_string()),
    };
    let mut statement = conn.prepare(&format!(
        "INSERT INTO comments (message, author) VALUES (?1, ?2) RETURNING {}",
        ROW_QUERY
    ))?;
    let inserted = statement.query_row([&comment.message, &comment.author], row_to_comment)?;
    return respond_with_json(201, &inserted);
}

fn check_authorization(request: &Request, admin_password: &str) -> bool {
    let auth_header = request
        .headers()
        .iter()
        .find(|h| h.field.equiv("Authorization"));
    return match auth_header {
        Some(header) => {
            let prefix = "bearer ";
            if header.value.len() < prefix.len()
                || header.value.as_str()[..prefix.len()].to_lowercase() != prefix
            {
                false;
            }
            let incoming_password = &header.value.as_str()[prefix.len()..];
            bool::from(
                incoming_password
                    .as_bytes()
                    .ct_eq(admin_password.as_bytes()),
            )
        }
        None => false,
    };
}

fn update_comment(
    request: &mut Request,
    id: i64,
    admin_password: &str,
    conn: &rusqlite::Connection,
) -> Result<RouteResponse, Box<dyn Error>> {
    if !check_authorization(request, admin_password) {
        return respond_with_json(401, "Unauthorized");
    }
    let updates: UpdateComment = match read_json(request) {
        Ok(comment) => comment,
        Err(e) => return respond_with_json(400, &e.to_string()),
    };
    let mut values: Vec<&dyn rusqlite::ToSql> = Vec::new();
    let mut query = String::new();
    query.push_str("UPDATE COMMENTS SET ");
    let approved = updates.approved.unwrap_or_default();
    let message = updates.message.clone().unwrap_or_default();
    let author = updates.author.clone().unwrap_or_default();

    if updates.approved.is_some() {
        values.push(&approved);
        if values.len() > 1 {
            query.push_str(", ");
        }
        query.push_str(&format!("approved = ?{}", values.len()));
    }
    if updates.message.is_some() {
        values.push(&message);
        if values.len() > 1 {
            query.push_str(", ");
        }
        query.push_str(&format!("message = ?{}", values.len()));
    }
    if updates.author.is_some() {
        values.push(&author);
        if values.len() > 1 {
            query.push_str(", ");
        }
        query.push_str(&format!("author = ?{}", values.len()));
    }
    if values.is_empty() {
        return respond_with_json(400, "No updates provided");
    }
    query.push_str(format!(" WHERE id = {} RETURNING {}", id, ROW_QUERY).as_str());
    let mut statement = conn.prepare(query.as_str())?;
    let updated = statement.query_row(values.as_slice(), row_to_comment)?;
    return respond_with_json(201, &updated);
}

fn initialize_database(path: &Path) -> Result<rusqlite::Connection, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let conn = rusqlite::Connection::open(path)?;
    conn.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        message TEXT NOT NULL,
        author TEXT,
        approved BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)",
        (),
    )?;
    return Ok(conn);
}

fn start_server(
    port: u16,
    db_conn: rusqlite::Connection,
    admin_password: &str,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let server = match Server::http(("0.0.0.0", port)) {
        Ok(server) => server,
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
    };
    let patch_regex = Regex::new(r"^/(\d+)$")?;
    for mut request in server.incoming_requests() {
        let route = (request.method(), request.url());
        println!("Handling {} {}", route.0, route.1);
        let response = match route {
            (&tiny_http::Method::Get, "/") => list_comments(&mut request, &db_conn, admin_password),
            (&tiny_http::Method::Post, "/") => create_comment(&mut request, &db_conn),
            _ if route.0 == &tiny_http::Method::Put && patch_regex.is_match(route.1) => {
                let id = patch_regex.captures(route.1).unwrap()[1].parse::<i64>()?;
                update_comment(&mut request, id, admin_password, &db_conn)
            }
            _ => Ok(default_response(404)),
        };
        match response {
            Ok(response) => send_response(request, response),
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
                send_response(request, default_response(500))
            }
        }
    }
    return Ok(());
}

fn send_response(request: Request, response: RouteResponse) {
    if let Err(e) = request.respond(response) {
        eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
    }
}

#[derive(clap::Parser, Debug)]
#[command(version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(short, long, required = true)]
    secret: String,

    #[arg(short, long, default_value_t = 8001)]
    port: u16,

    #[arg(short, long, default_value = "data.db")]
    db_path: PathBuf,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let args = Args::parse();
    let conn = initialize_database(args.db_path.as_path())?;
    start_server(args.port, conn, &args.secret)?;
    return Ok(());
}

